# Mass Thunderbird folder to Gnus nnfolder conversions

Tags: directory, thunderbird, gnus

I'm pondering the idea of importing a few thousand Thunderbird folders, each folder containing many emails of course, as a set of Emacs' Gnus mailgroups.  Each mailgroup name would be derived from the folder hierarchy.  Because of the quantity, the work is going to be fairly tedious, so I would automate this massive import if possible.

Among the available backends, **nnfolder** seems the most promising in this case.  I presume it would be better to populate the mailgroups from within Gnus.  Otherwise, I would have to thoroughly understand the **nnfolder** format, and this might require many iterations before I really get it right.  Moreover, as email continues to flow in, iterations may become difficult to properly organize without loosing anything.

I guess I have to *respool* everything, under the constraint that the selected mailgroup is a function of the Thunderbird origin, overriding the standard Gnus selection mechanism.  I did some Gnus coding in the past, but since I did not touch Emacs for a dozen years, it is all very rusty.  I'm a bit lost about how to approach this task as efficiently and quickly as possible.  So my question: how would *you* handle it?  Or is there some clever Gnus hidden corner that I should explore more deeply? :-)

François

***P.S.*** After I wrote this question, I found out that Gnus has a nice, helping function towards this goal.  The idea is to first copy all Thunderbird folder files within the `~/Mail` directory, as they are for the contents, but properly renamed.  Once this done, `M-x nnfolder-generate-active-file` does at once, for each copied folder, edit the contents, leave a `~` backup, generate NOV data, create one mailgroup and, of course, adjust the `~/Mail/active` file.

To copy the folders underneath the `~/.thunderbird/LOGIN/Mail/Local Folders/` directory, I wrote a small Python script.  It ignores all `.msf` files, and recurse within `.sbd` directories.  The folder path name, relative to `Local Folders/`, has all its `.sbd/` strings turned into periods to produce the mailgroup name, also lowering case, turning spaces and underlines to dashes, and handling other special characters appropriately.  In particular, non-ASCII characters are not handled properly, **nnfolder** is confusing UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 here and there.  The script also has to skip `msgfilterrules.dat` and likely `drafts`, `junk` and such things.

I notice two details requiring attention :

- Thunderbird itself can be used to compact folders before copying them, otherwise one might unwillingly recover messages which were already deleted.
- `(setq nnmail-use-long-file-names t)` is needed in `~/.emacs` prior to the whole operation.

The batch transformation aborted, saying it is not able to decrypt one of the message.  I moved the offending folder out of the way, and then, the lengthy operation succeeded.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make your question(s) more obvious. They seem to be somewhere in the *middle* of your text.